# H tag on top of div tag using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to display the H tag on top of the `.entry-image` div, so it appears as if `.entry-image` is a background for the H tag.

This is my code's structure:

```
<div class="entry-image">
<a href="http://metromom.net/blog-category/newspaper-article/" rel="bookmark">
<img src="myphoto.jpg">
</a>
</div>

<h4 class="entry-title">Title </h4>
```

I am unable to edit the HTML, because it is output by a WordPress plugin; and therefore require an approach that uses CSS only.

Comment: Do you want the image to be a background image?

Comment: place it on the top ...

Comment: Your question is too broad. Because as it, i can answer that you have to write `<h1> You title </h1>` just before your div. On just after your div's opening tag. But i think this is not what you want. Or maybe you want your `h4` to be display in your div but with css only and not in the the html structure. So we will need your css also.

Comment: @Narxx yes, I want the div to be background of the h4

Comment: @AlexVand I cannot change the code structure since this is a wordpress plugin. I'll just manipulate using CSS.

Comment: @Narxx why adding a working snippet for this code ? what is the purpose .. there is no issue or behavior that we can see ... he only provided a code with no CSS and asking us to do the job, so what a working snippet will add to the question ?

Comment: So we will need a link to your site or the css for this html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least 2 solutions:

Just change the order of H tag and image (easy and correct solution):

```html
<h4 class="entry-title">Title </h4>
<div class="entry-image">
<a href="http://metromom.net/blog-category/newspaper-article/" rel="bookmark">
<img src="myphoto.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

Or use CSS to position both of them. It is more tricky and has more "fixed" values, but it doesn't change Your DOM structure. The most important thing here to make it work is to set the "position" value to "relative" or "absolute" for parent of BOTH H and image ("main" element in the snippet below):

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.entry-image {
  /* Adapt the margin-top value to make space for H tag */
  margin-top: 3em;
  /*
  Or position it absolute

  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  */

}

.entry-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

<div class="entry-image">
<a href="http://metromom.net/blog-category/newspaper-article/" rel="bookmark">
<img src="myphoto.jpg">
</a>
</div>

<h4 class="entry-title">Title </h4>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a reliable way to do this with CSS, based on the structure of your HTML. Ideally, you'd need to be able to move the H4 inside the "entry-image" div, and then absolutely position it:

```css
.entry-image {
  position: relative;
}

.entry-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-image">
    <h4 class="entry-title">Title </h4>
      <a href="http://metromom.net/blog-category/newspaper-article/" rel="bookmark">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      </a>
    </div>
```

**However**, if you can't edit the code output by the plugin - you might be able to wrap a container around it (depending on how/where the output is generated in your theme). You could do something like this:

```css
.your-wrapping-container {
  position: relative;
}

.entry-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-wrapping-container">

<div class="entry-image">
      <a href="http://metromom.net/blog-category/newspaper-article/" rel="bookmark">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      </a>
    </div>

    <h4 class="entry-title">Title </h4>
    
</div>
```

If this isn't also possible - Javascript would be your next option, as you would need to calculate the "entry-image" div's position, relative to the document; and then use this information to position the "entry-title" element.

Something like this could help you:

```js
var entryImagePosition = $('.entry-image').offset();

$('.entry-title').css({position: 'absolute', top: entryImagePosition.top+15, left: entryImagePosition.left+15});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-image">
      <a href="http://metromom.net/blog-category/newspaper-article/" rel="bookmark">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      </a>
    </div>

    <h4 class="entry-title">Title </h4>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually there is a fairly reliable way: `order` from the Flexbox spec

Comment: I didn't consider the `order` property from the Flexbox spec, because it wouldn't do what they wanted. They're not asking to have the H tag sit above the image, they're asking for it to sit on top of the image. It's for this reason I recommended absolutely positioning the H tag.